# Convert SYSDATETIMEOFFSET ( ) to HH:MM AM/PM

Tags: sql, date-formatting

I am using the query:

```
select LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET ( ), 22), 12)) as RecvdTime
```

It gives me: `6:27:16 PM`

I need to remove second part & print it as `6:27 PM` (with one space between `27` & `PM`)

I tried to change the query but was not successful.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET ( ), 108) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET ( ), 9),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.  I can not test it at the moment but it should give you the space between the minutes and the AM/PM.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET ( ),100),7)),7),'AM',' AM'),'PM',' PM')
```